# After I've validated if some $_POST variables are correct, I want my window to close. How do I do this with JQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

```
<?php 
   if($_POST["some_variable"]){
       echo "this window should be closing now";
   }
?>
```

How would I call the JQuery code to close the window, and what would the function be?

The window was opened with a code resembling the following...

```
$('.new_window').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        var center = 'height=436,width=465,top=' + ((screen.height - 436) / 2) + ',left=' + ((screen.width - 465) / 2);
        var address = 'popup.php?fid=' + $(this).attr('id');
        window.open(address, 'new_window', center);
    });
});
```

I'm guessing the code goes somewhere inside my JS file, and is somehow called from within the "if" braces.

Some clarification: The php in my example doesn't really matter. The gist of the thing is, I need to close the window if the PHP code makes it to that code block. My database should also be updated before the window closes (not in the example code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of Javascript should do the trick:

```
<script>
    window.close();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually thought about using this, but I'm still new to web programming, and wasn't sure if I could run JS like that validly. It could be infinitely useful to use PHP and JS like this together.